# fallback iterative sql queries

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I'm looking for a pattern for combining multiple SQL query results with this behavior:

'try query A, if the results are not empty return them '

'if A returned nothing try query B, if the results are not empty return them '

'if B returned nothing try query C, if the results are not empty return them '

'if C returned nothing try query D, if the results are not empty return them '

'if A, B, C, D all returned empty sets, return an empty set'

Any suggestions? I'm aiming for simplicity and performance and while I'm hoping for relatively generic SQL I'm specifically running on sqlite and mysql.

TIA.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQLite?  Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Can these queries return more than one row?

Comment: @CL. Yes, these queries can return more than one row - which is why I ditched my initial approach using CASE conditionals.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  I'm using sqlite at the moment, but ultimately I need to do the same in another implementation using mysql.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, you have to do separate checks for whether the queries return anything:

```
WITH A AS (SELECT ...),
     B AS (SELECT ...),
     C AS (SELECT ...),
     D AS (SELECT ...)
SELECT * FROM A
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM B WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM A)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM C WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM A)
                  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM B)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM D WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM A)
                  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM B)
                  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM C);
```

(MySQL does not support WITH; use views, or copy the subqueries.)

This is inefficient.
It would be a better idea to write your own code (in the calling program, or as a stored procedure) that executes the four queries separately and checks for results.

Comment: Thanks much @CL. As you suggest because performance here is essential my problem is really outside the scope of finding the right SQL syntax, so I'm reconsidering the approach in my application code.